# Waiting for new options to be generated for select in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a `select` element with `ng-options` set to a certain expression, using AngularJS. If the options change, then I need to make sure that the jQuery plugin that I'm using for displaying the `select` element *also* refreshes. So, if the options have changed, then I need to make a refresh call.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the options change"?

Answer (score 0):

I will direct you to [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.com/), we have a generic directive ui-jq that may just do what you want. The basic problem is that angular does not know about your jquery plugin making updates to angular's model. Typically, you need to listen for the external event and use [$scope.apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) let angular know.

Comment: I don't think the problem is Angular not knowing about events seen by the jQuery plugin (in my case [this one](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/)). I do see the updated options on my model, and the code *does* stick them into the select. However, if I refresh the plugin, the options haven't been set on the underlying `select` yet. Using a timeout works, but I don't want to be dependent on that.

Comment: If using a timeout is working, then its because (I believe) the digest cycle is happening during the interval. I still stand by usage of $scope.apply since it causes the digest cycle to happen. I could be wrong but I think its worth a try. If you could put together a jsfiddle or plunker example this would help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but: if you want to watch for models changing, use `scope.$watch:`

```
   scope.$watch('name', function(newVal) {
     // do something with the new value of scope.name
   });
```

But if you're specifically using a select, then definitely check out angular-ui, as Dan Doyon suggested. It has a plugin that should take care of what you need.